# How can I have a config file for Silverlight OOB?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

I have a `Silverlight` application with some `appSettings` in my `Web.Config` file. Now I want to make it `OOB`, what is the best way to handle this.

Should I `download config file` using `WebClient` when running in `OOB`.

Please suggest if you have any good method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "app settings" in a Web.Config are only used by the web/server part of your Silverlight application. Not by the client application (unless you pass them on to the client).

It should not make any difference if your Silverlight App is running OOB... It is still just a client app, requiring information from your web server (if you wish to pass them on).

Basically, you should not need to change anything, unless you are doing something wrong in the first place. *Can you explain what sort of settings you are needing in your client application?*

Comment: I have some service references, so their URLs, and some FTP Ips, Domain name, some module names etc. has been stored in the Web.Config

Comment: It is a security risk to download your entire web.config file to the client as it is sent *in the clear* and therefore readable (including your connection strings or other sensitive settings). You need to separate out your "application" settings (e.g. into another XML file) and send only that.